# Pasar dato de TS al HTML - Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic

Lo que sucede es que estoy configurando mi app para poder tomar fotos con la galeria y todo eso ya funciona bien, llego hasta el punto donde mi funcion retorna la imagen que tomo en Base 64 pero no logro imprimirla en el HTML, estoy trabajando en Angular con Ionic

```
takePhoto() {
    this.imagePickerProvider.get().then(response => {
      //console.log(response);
      let imgB64 = response;
    });
  }
```

```
<div id="fotoPerfil_cont" (click)="takePhoto()">
      <div class="fotoPerfil_mask" id="user_fotoPerfil" style="background-image: imagenBase64;">
        <img src="assets/images/profile/photo.svg">
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ningún lado estas invocando tu variable en el html y sin mencionar que la promesa que te devuelve `this.imagePickerProvider` la matas allí mismo y no la puedes usar fuera del `.then()` por lo que tienes que hacer es agregar una variable antes del constructor que guarde tu imagen

```
imgB64: Any

constructor(){} //Solo lo pongo para que sepas ubicarte, no que lo coloques
```

Ya luego en tu método, en vez de declarar la variable, le asignas la que tenias antes

```
takePhoto() {
    this.imagePickerProvider.get().then(response => {
      //console.log(response);
      this.imgB64 = response;
    });
  }
```

Ya luego en el html puedes agregar la imagen codificada con la siguiente etiqueta `img` y para pasar variables al html lo usas con las doble llaves

```
<img src= {{ imgB64 }} style="width:100%">
```

Y con eso, muestras la imagen que tenes. Me cuentas que tal, feliz día!